# How to use sessions variables in Asynchronous method CallBack in ASP.NET using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asynchronous

I want to  use sessions variables in Asynchronous method CallBack in ASP.NET using C#:

```
    HttpContext _HttpContext;

    RequestDownloadDelegate del = new RequestDownloadDelegate(downloadFactory.GetContent(PageType.StockRegister).GetDataForExport);

IAsyncResult async = del.BeginInvoke(null, CallBackDownloadDelegate, null);

public void CallBackDownloadDelegate(IAsyncResult async)
    {

        AsyncResult ar = (AsyncResult)async;
        RequestDownloadDelegate del = (RequestDownloadDelegate)ar.AsyncDelegate;
        List<object> Content = del.EndInvoke(async);

        List<DownloadItem> downloadList = new List<DownloadItem>();
        if (_HttpContext.Session["DownloadItemList"] != null)
        {
            downloadList = _HttpContext.Session["DownloadItemList"] as List<DownloadItem>;

        }

    }
```

When calling back `_HttpContext.Session` is getting `null`.

Comment: If you know the null is due to the async (you have tested the value of your session variable outside the async thread), then why not simply pass it to the async method rather than accessing it from inside?

Comment: Hey Shannon Thanks for your reply, but can you explain me how can i pass it to the async method and how can i get in callback method. thanks again